# VBA that selects specific range of cells and deletes only the highlighted cells and shifts up

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new at using VBA.  I'm creating a macro that scans through each cell within a range to detect any cells filled with yellow, deleting them, and shifting up. Then it should move to the next cell in the data table.

I'm getting "Run-time error '1004': Delete method of Range class failed", which I think is about the Range object I declared, but I'm not sure how I should properly implement this or if there's a better way to execute this VBA?  This is what I have so far.

```
Sub DeleteHighlight()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("A6:O3863")
    If ActiveCell.Interior.Color <> RGB(255,255,0) Then
       ActiveCell.Delete Shift:=x1ToUp
       Exit For
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cell` not `ActiveCell` and `xlToUp` not `x1ToUp`. Also you will skip cells since you're iterating down and shifting up.

Comment: `.Color <> RGB(255,255,0)` is a cell not yellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Warcupine is right that you're going to end up skipping rows. Instead, you should loop from the bottom to the top.

```
Sub DeleteHighlight()

Dim lRow As Long

'find last row
lRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

'loop backwards
For i = lRow To 1 Step -1
If Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
Rows(i).Delete
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback on the VBA.  Your code had helped solve what I was aiming to do!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Scan upwards to avoid missing the cell below the deleted one. (Untested)

```vb
Sub DeleteHighlight()
    Dim r as Long, c as Long
    For r = 3863 to 6 Step -1
        For c = 1 To 15 'O
            If Cells(r,c).Interior.Color = RGB(255,255,0) Then
                Cells(r,c).Delete Shift:=xlToUp
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```